# Whats the output format of "df -ki" in AIX?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, shell, aix, df

I just wanna know the output format (the order of columns) when running the command `df -ki` in an AIX system. I dont have access to an AIX system , and since it doesnt run on x86 machines , i cant try it out in a virtual machine either. Can someone with access to AIX reply with an ACTUAL OUTPUT OF RUNNING THE COMMAND IN AIX ?

I want to run this command as part of a script and parse the output for specific fields and hence need the output format .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's from an old release, but anyway:

```
aixterm1:/u/grp/svenw> uname -a
AIX aixterm1 3 4 0006414D4C00

aixterm1:/u/grp/svenw> df -ki
Filesystem    1024-blocks      Free %Used    Iused %Iused Mounted on
/dev/hd4            81920     45012   46%     2716     7% /
/dev/hd2          1720320    108080   94%    42070    10% /usr
```

Comment: thanks for the answer sven . Can you also give the output of "df -k" ?

Comment: @theneoindian: The output is identical for `df -k`.